# How to stop a running function with another function

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, function

**I want to have a loop function which "runs forever" but when i call another function it stop the loop function**  Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
from tkinter import*
import random, time, os, threading, pyautogui
fn = '1'
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\mypcname\Desktop\screenrec\videos')

#waits 5 seconds before calling stop_function to stop the loop
def amount_of_time():
    threading.Timer(5.0, stop_function).start()


#takes screenshot every 2 seconds
def take_screenshot():
    global fn
    while True:
        global time
        time.sleep(2)
        fn = str(fn)
        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        screenshot.save(os.getcwd()+r'\frame'+fn+'.png')
        fn = int(fn)
        fn +=1


t = threading.Thread(target=take_screenshot)  


def stop_function():
    take_screenshot.destroy()


#starts take_screenshot loop
t.start()
amount_of_time()
```

Comment: This code won't run for other reasons. You import `time` only to redefine it as a function and then declare it as a global variable.

Comment: Yes I realised this after i ran the code again, i have now updated it, it should run fine (except i still haven't figured out how to stop a function)